# delete definit rows from txt file in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, numpy

I have a text file containing 100000 rows and I read it with numpy.loadtxt. I want to delete the rows which their first column have the value 2 and 3.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have loaded your txt into an array, say `a`:

```
a = a[((a[:,0]!=2) & (a[:,0]!=3)),:]
```

Should take the rows where the first column value is different of 2 and 3.

Comment: or `a = a[~np.in1d(a[:,0], (2,3))]`

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is indeed more elegant and much easier to expand for more conditions...

Comment: Yeah, for only two conditions, yours makes as much sense (and is probably faster). For many though, it becomes difficult.

Comment: But I want to delete these rows from the text file.

Comment: @user2154410 you can write the text file again after doing the filter showed in the answer, using `np.savetxt('new_file.txt', a)`

Comment: in the case of a text file containing only on column this command does not work a = a[~np.in1d(a[:,0], (1))]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices
What is the wrong?

Comment: @user2154410 in this case just do: `a = a[~np.in1d(a[:], (1))]`, i.e. change `a[:,0]` by `a[:]`, since when just one column is present the obtained output is a 1-D array, which does not contain the second index...